# Installing Snappy Ubuntu Core on an old Android phone

Tags: ubuntu-core

Is it possible to download a Snappy Ubuntu Core .img file?

The thing is, I want to see if I can run Ubuntu on an old Nexus One phone by following the steps showed in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqw4Xaqscvc

Thanks in advance for your support.

P.S. For a wider exposition of my intentions, whatt I really want to do is to be able to run a platform called "Johnny-Five" on my phone so I can then connect my phone to an Arduino board. Johnny-five is based on node.js and that's why I need Ubuntu on the phone, to be able to install node.js. (I'm just speculating since I don't really know If I can do all of this stuff).

I got the idea from this tutorials:

Getting Started with Johnny Five for IoT with Tomomi Imura (Part 1)
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGOp4se0gqkuaRzxPiGjYtA

and there's a part 2,

Getting Started with Johnny Five for IoT with Tomomi Imura (Part 2)

Essentially, I want to substitute the laptop used in the tutorials with a phone connected to the Arduino board.

Thanks, again!

Comment: There appears to be an aparently abandoned port of Ubuntu Touch for the Nexus One. Not sure if this would be acceptable for you or not. See this wiki page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: I would suggest finding out the specifics of the board used on your old phone and which kernel it ran and then bring it up on the [snapcraft mailing list](https://lists.snapcraft.io/mailman/listinfo/snapcraft) to see if kernel support can be made available.

Comment: Ok, great suggestions. I checked the abandoned port of Ubuntu Touch for the Nexus One, but I need to do that with more detail since it appears to be an unfinished work. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: Phone specs, chipset: Qualcomm QSD8250 Snapdragon S1,    CPU: 1 Ghz Scorpion, Architecture: armv71, Kernel version: 2.6.35.7-ge0fb012 (htc-kernel@and18-231), Android: 2.3.4, It has 512 MB of RAM, It is a rooted phone, It has some apps installed such as Linux Deploy and Busybox which as far as I know do make possible the installation. I.ve seen videos of people who actually have installed some ubuntu images on it. I've tested some images with no success.The thing is which Ubuntu core image would be the most suitable to use? I'll try the snapcraft mailing list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this question still bugs you, but I guess the best starting point might be here: http://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/gadget and espacially this site : http://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/reference/gadget.